# SSRS Report Server render and update values to database table?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportserver

Can we do some server settings on the SSRS server by which any report is called then this will update these values to database table for e.g.
I have a rdl file and a table tblLogDetails. When any user hits a print button in my application then rdl file rendered up and at the same time 
reportserver will update/insert tbllogdetail columns UserID, PrintTime,PrintDate, IsPrint flag a boolean value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tracking report usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179082/tracking-report-usage)

Comment: I think you may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30940931/4840746) useful. (can't flag this question as duplicate because no news from the user who asked the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert a specific Dataset in each report that updates your tblLogDetails table.

Just set up the dataset as you would normally, but have the proc or script update your log table.

Comment: Yes I think this is a great idea which works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dbo.ExecutionLogStorage` table in the report server database to render some details about ever report execution. It wont show you print time and date but will show you a history.

Also this approach will only show you the SQL user that you have assigned to execute reports. Hence if you are trying to record users in a custom web application running reports you may need to consider a different approach altogether.

Possibly an event listener in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Guidelines in brief

A possible solution is the trick with Java Script.

It is necessary to listen PRINT BUTTON - INPUT with name = "ctl32$ctl05$ctl06$tl00$ctl00$ctl00" click.

Also need to pick up values from a number of INPUT or SELECT parameter like this: SELECT id ="ctl32ctl04_ctl03_ddValue" name ="ctl32$ctl04$ctl03$ddValue">

Prepare parameter values and send them to certain methods (HTTPPOST) in the Web application